# HTTPS Keep-Alive to reduce handshake time

Tags: web-services, keep-alive, androidhttpclient

So I have an app that make several requests to the server on a button click.
I noticed there's HTTPS handshake overhead for every single call.

[image: Https Handshake]

How can I re-use the connection in this case so there's no need of handshake overhead on each back-to-back request?

```
POST https://myserver:8080/Service/GetContact HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 113
Host: myserver:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I thought `Connection: Keep-Alive` is suppose to take care of that for me?

Comment: Is there a `Connection: close` in the response headers? If so the server is explicitly rejecting a keep alive.

Comment: If you look at the picture, it always show as a pair of HTTP/HTTPS for each call that I make. If I inspect the HTTP  (Tunnel to) it has `Connection: close` in the response, but the HTTPS ones (which actually returned the data) do not close connection.

Comment: And I've confirmed that Keep-Alive is enabled on our server, so that shouldn't be the cause of it.